# How to formulate a JOIN in a typed query?

Tags: java, sql, jpa-2.0

I want to create a typed query.

```
TypedQuery<PubThread> query = em.createQuery(queryString, PubThread.class);
query.setParameter("threadId", threadId);
List<PubThread> otherPubThreads = query.getResultList();
```

In the queryString is the following SQL (currently without param and static selection values)

```
SELECT pt2 FROM pubthread pt2   
JOIN pub_pubthread ppt2 ON pt2.id = ppt2.pubThreads_id  
JOIN pub p2 ON ppt2.pups_id = p2.id     
JOIN pubcategory pc2 ON p2.pubCategoryId = pc2.id   
WHERE pt2.id != 1 and EXISTS (      
    SELECT DISTINCT(pt.id) 
    FROM pubthread pt       
    JOIN pub_pubthread ppt ON pt.id = ppt.pubThreads_id         
    JOIN pub p ON ppt.pups_id = p.id        
    JOIN pubcategory pc ON p.pubCategoryId = pc.id      
    WHERE pc2.id = pc.id and pt.id = 1  
)
```

It does work, if I limit the String to a simple select: `SELECT Distinct(pt2.id), pt2.name FROM pubthread pt2`. As soon I add a JOIN line to it, it will complain. How do you properly query with JOINS in JPA? The error is: 
`org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: ON near line 1, column 81 [SELECT pt2 FROM com.brayan.webapp.model.PubThread pt2 JOIN pub_pubthread ppt2 ON pt2.id = ppt2.pubThreads_id ]`

Doubtless, a criteria query would be nicer. I accept that as part of the solution space.

Comment: Why use DISTINCT in subquery contained in exists? Is more fast without it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got it. See below a fully example of joins. It consists of:

- multiple joins (join-chaining)
- a subquery
- a predicate correlation/equation over join tables, other than the root table.

I also commented the obsolete code lines for other to see what a wrong approach.

CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
        CriteriaQuery mainQuery = criteriaBuilder
                .createQuery(PubThread.class);

```
    // 1) MainQuery
    // Create the FROM
    Root<PubThread> rootPubThread = mainQuery.from(PubThread.class);
    // Create the JOIN from the first select: join-chaining. You only need the return for ordering. e.g. cq.orderBy(cb.asc(categoryJoin.get(Pub_.title)));
    Join<Pub, PubCategory> categoryJoin = rootPubThread.join(PubThread_.pups).join(Pub_.pubCategory);
    // Create the WHERE
    mainQuery.where(criteriaBuilder.not(criteriaBuilder.equal(rootPubThread.get(PubThread_.id), threadId)));
    // Create the SELECT, at last
    mainQuery.select(rootPubThread).distinct(true);

    // 2) Subquery
    Subquery<PubThread> subquery = mainQuery.subquery(PubThread.class); 
    Root<PubThread> rootPubThreadSub = subquery.from(PubThread.class); 
    //subquery.where(criteriaBuilder.equal(rootPubThread.get(PubThread_.id), threadId));
    Join<Pub, PubCategory> categoryJoinSub = rootPubThreadSub.join(PubThread_.pups).join(Pub_.pubCategory);
    subquery.select(rootPubThreadSub);

    //Predicate correlatePredicate = criteriaBuilder.equal(rootPubThreadSub.get(PubThread_.id), rootPubThread);
    Predicate correlatePredicate = criteriaBuilder.and(
            //criteriaBuilder.equal(rootPubThreadSub.get(PubThread_.id), rootPubThread),
            criteriaBuilder.equal(categoryJoinSub.get(PubCategory_.id), categoryJoin.get(PubCategory_.id)),

            criteriaBuilder.equal(rootPubThreadSub.get(PubThread_.id), threadId)
            );
    subquery.where(correlatePredicate);     

    //Predicate correlatePredicate = criteriaBuilder.equal(rootPubThreadSub.get(PubThread_.id), rootPubThread);
    Predicate mainPredicate = criteriaBuilder.and(
            criteriaBuilder.not(criteriaBuilder.equal(rootPubThread.get(PubThread_.id), threadId)),
            criteriaBuilder.exists(subquery)
            );
    //cq.where(criteriaBuilder.exists(subquery));
    mainQuery.where(mainPredicate);
```

Answer (score 2):

When you call `createQuery` you have to write HQL but not SQL (your `queryString` is not `HQL`).
In HQL you have to join objects according to your mapping entities.
If you sill need SQL query use `createNativeQuery` method.
See [documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html#queryhql-select) about how to create HQL query.

Comment: Hi Alex, Yes, I know (that's why I have placed pt2 in the projection of the first line). However, you are right, I'm certainly not familiar writing JOINs in HQL. Also; I need typed queries. Criteria queries would be even nicer.

Comment: Okay, I go down the road with JPA Critera Queries. http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gjivm.html